# MigraDoc Pdf long word rendering

Tags: pdf, render, migradoc, word-break

What is about word-breaking.

I have a purpose to render LONG word in pdf, and I need to replace part of word on the next row. So now I get word that starts after some indent and finishes after right page side (I don't see word's end).

I use something like this:

```
var addInfo = paragraph.AddFormattedText("LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TIIIIIIIIIIIITLE");
```

I didn't find any tips about in MigraDoc documentation...

Of course I can implement the logic for splitting words up by myself, and I'll do this, if there is no native solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column text overflowing out of column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973366/column-text-overflowing-out-of-column-width)

Answer (score 0):

MigraDoc breaks sentences at spaces, hyphens, and soft hyphens. A single long word without any of these won't get broken.

Try something useful ("The quick brown fox ...") and breaking will work.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40975554/162529