# Column text overflowing out of column width

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, migradoc

I am using Migradoc to generate a table and populating some dynamic data for few columns, I have defined column width while defining table structure as-

```
Table table = new Table();
Column column = table.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(6));
column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
table.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(6));
table.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(8));
```

Now the third column is having data (`acs800-07-1234a-5+asdf+asdf+qwer+wert+2345+rg+2345+ag+35+qwe1252rg+34tgh+24rg+253rg+23rgh+235rgh+@34gh+23rg-4s544`) , but it's overflowing the column and getting truncated towards the right side of page. It's automatically wrapped but not correctly , **some text is lost in the second line. See image:**

[image]

Any pointers to fix this issue in wrapping text would be appreciated.

**UPDATE-** ( Snippet showing how table data is added)

```
Row row = table.AddRow();
Cell cell = row.Cells[0];
cell.AddParagraph("ACS880-104");
cell = row.Cells[1];
cell.AddParagraph("R1 – R10");
cell = row.Cells[2];            
cell.AddParagraph("acs800-07-1234a-5+asdf+asdf+qwer+wert+2345+rg+2345+ag+35+qwe+125+2rg+34tgh+24rg+253rg+23rgh+235rgh+@34gh+23rg-4s544");
```

Comment: how do you add the text to the table? `Paragraph` ? `FormattedText`? `TextFrame` ?

Comment: Is this a real word type code or will there be spaces and hyphens when using real data?

Comment: @MongZhu I am adding text using Paragraph- also updated snippet in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MigraDoc automatically breaks lines at spaces, hyphens, and soft hyphens.

You have a long text without spaces and without hyphens. The easy solution: insert soft hyphens where you want to allow line breaks to occur (e.g. a soft hyphen after each "+" sign).

Update: As of version 1.50 you can also use zero-width non-joiners to mark locations where line breaks are allowed. Use soft hyphens to get line breaks with a hyphen, use zero-width non-joiners for line breaks without hyphens.

Comment: yes this is real world data, can you explain a bit more how we can insert and then remove these soft hyphens after wrapping?

Comment: I have explored the stuff with soft hyphen on my own and also posted my solution below, thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

As Migradoc has limitation of breaking lines at only spaces,hyphens and soft hyphens i have inserted `space` after everyy 45 chars(your choice as per column width) and hence the value is wrapped properly without having any effect of shown output(no extra chars visible)

**Code Snippet -**

```
    String myString = "acs800-07-1234a-5+asdf+asdf+qwer+wert+2345+rg+2345+ag+35+qwe+125+2rg+34tgh+24rg+253rg+23rgh+235rgh+@34gh+23rg-4s544";

    cell.AddParagraph(Regex.Replace(myString, ".{45}", "$0 "));
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]