# MigraDoc Table cell text overlap

Tags: pdf, text, cell, migradoc

I want PDF with table and I am using  MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table to create table. Table cell content overlapping when content has "text with no space".
Is there any direct solution rather than manually creating text wrap function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column text overflowing out of column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973366/column-text-overflowing-out-of-column-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text will break at spaces, at hyphens, at soft hyphens, and at zero-width non-joiners.

If you do not care where the linebreak occurs, just insert a zero-width non-joiner between each pair of characters or at suitable locations (e.g. for URLs after each slash or dot).

Soft hyphens between syllables will look better for human-readable text.

Comment: Actually I generate report with datatable which contains thousands of rows. Is it good practice to manipulate datatable data to add add zero-width non-joiner or spae or hyphen?

Comment: @Learner MS Word automatically breaks anywhere to avoid overlap, so when generating RTF you do not have to do anything. MigraDoc only breaks at specific characters, so if you want to create nice PDF files you may have to mark locations for linebreaks if the table contains data that is not the normal "human readable" type. Using zero-width non-joiners has no impact on the representation (except the linebreak) and comes closest to the behavior of MS Word. If you insert the non-joiners only at "meaningful locations" it will even look better than with Word.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: From SO Help: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers